# How to remove row borders in a specific column?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a HTML table with three columns. In one of these three columns, I want to remove lines from it.

I tried codes like `border-style: hidden; padding: 0px;` `colspan` and `rowspan` but they don't help.

```html
<table style="width:100%; margin-block-start: 5px;font-size:20px;border: 1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <th style="padding: 15px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;">Tasks</th>
    <th style="padding: 15px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;">Sales Performance</th> 
    <th style="padding: 15px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;">Staffs' Annual Leave</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Yesterday</i></td>
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;border-style: hidden;"></td> 
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Today</i></td>
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;border-style: hidden;"></td> 
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Tomorrow</i></td>
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;border-style: hidden;"></td> 
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Upcoming</i></td>
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;border-style: hidden;"></td> 
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Some other day</i></td>
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;border-style: hidden;"></td> 
    <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

my expectation

[image]

reality

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a mock design, how exactly you want.

Comment: Which column of which row? By lines do you mean border? You may use this jsfiddle - take a screen shot and point row and column https://codepen.io/pzombade/pen/XOWNdW?editors=1111

Comment: border-style: hidden seems to work ?

Comment: I added images already. Please check them under "my expectation" and "reality".

Comment: Check my answer below if it doesn't work please comment your problem

Comment: @PrashantZombade thanks for recommending the tool. I will use it if I have other questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td.no-data {
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; margin-block-start: 5px;font-size:20px;border: 1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <th>Tasks</th>
    <th>Sales Performance</th> 
    <th>Staffs' Annual Leave</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i>Yesterday</i></td>
    <td class="no-data"></td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i>Today</i></td>
    <td class="no-data"></td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i>Tomorrow</i></td>
    <td class="no-data"></td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i>Upcoming</i></td>
    <td class="no-data"></td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i>Some other day</i></td>
    <td class="no-data"></td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually you don't even need to add that `no-data` class. You could just ignore the middle cells with `td:not(:nth-child(2)) { border: 1px solid black }`

Comment: @VilleKoo Yes I know ! He/She was using inline css I just gave this example to show that can be done simply by using class. Thanks for your suggestion though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `inline-style` with `class` or `data-attribute`

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.no-border {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%; margin-block-start: 5px;font-size:20px;border: 1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <th>Tasks</th>
    <th>Sales Performance</th>
    <th>Staffs' Annual Leave</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i>Yesterday</i>
    </td>
    <td class=" no-border"></td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i>Today</i>
    </td>
    <td class="no-border"></td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i>Tomorrow</i>
    </td>
    <td class="no-border"></td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i>Upcoming</i>
    </td>
    <td class="no-border"></td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i>Some other day</i>
    </td>
    <td class="no-border"></td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Glad to help @Kiki

Comment: @Kiki But this doesn't match to your expectation image !

Comment: @Sushil I added this CSS code:                                                                                             table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

Comment: @Sushil If it meets his/her desired output than it's great ! but I was just saying that it doesn't meet expected image he/she has given ! So then he/she should update his/her question with appropriate image !

Comment: @Kiki please don't use `inline-style`

Comment: @Sushil okay. But why tho?

Comment: @Kiki    For every property you want to change, using inline CSS requires you to look for the corresponding HTML code, instead of just looking inside clearly-defined and hopefully well-structured CSS files.

Comment: @Sushil I see. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Kiki ask if there's any other problem too,

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `border-collapse` style to the table and use `rowspan` attribute to span your first `<td>`.
when you *rowspan* your first `<td>`, you don't need to add any more `<td>` tags in the following `<tr>`s because the first `<td>` will span all the way down up to the value (number of rows to be spanned) of the `rowspan` attribute, for example `rowspan=5` will span up to the end of your current table.

```html
<table style="width:100%; margin-block-start: 5px;font-size:20px;border: 1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse">
    <tr>
        <th style="padding: 15px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;">Tasks</th>
        <th style="padding: 15px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;" >Sales Performance</th> 
        <th style="padding: 15px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;">Staffs' Annual Leave</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Yesterday</i></td>
        <td rowspan='5'</td>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Today</i></td>
  
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Tomorrow</i></td>
    
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Upcoming</i></td>
        
         <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Some other day</i></td>
    
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">94</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Please do not use inline styles

Comment: @mplungjan I'm showing the questioner what is needed to be changed in order to get the desired result. If I change the entire code he may suppose it was necessary in order to make it work because as you can see from his question he is a starter not professional.

Answer (score 1):

It works out just what I wanted after I added some lines of codes:

```
margin-block-start: 5px;

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

The first part is to lower down the table from the navigation bar.
The second part is to get what I expected my table to be.

Thank you for answering my question.

If you want to know rest of the codes, please check Sushil and Nawras's answers.

P.S. Yes, I am a starter to all of these.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `margin-block-start` in production since it's still an experimental technology ( [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start) ) Better if you just use the normal `margin` property

Comment: @VilleKoo thanks for sharing. I didn't know margin-block-start is still an experimental technology. Is margin-top the normal margin property?

Comment: Yes, you could use the `margin-top` property :)

Comment: @VilleKoo okay. I have corrected the code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-collapse: collapse;` for table tag.

```html
<table style="width:100%; margin-block-start: 5px;font-size:20px;border: 1px solid black;     border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
        <th style="padding: 15px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;">Tasks</th>
        <th style="padding: 15px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;">Sales Performance</th> 
        <th style="padding: 15px;text-align: left;border: 1px solid black;">Staffs' Annual Leave</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Yesterday</i></td>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;border-style: hidden;"></td> 
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Today</i></td>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;border-style: hidden;"></td> 
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Tomorrow</i></td>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;border-style: hidden;"></td> 
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Upcoming</i></td>
         <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;border-style: hidden;"></td> 
         <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">94</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;"><i>Some other day</i></td>
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;border-style: hidden;"></td> 
        <td style="padding: 15px;border: 1px solid black;">94</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: That result is not an improvement and does not match OPs expected result

Answer (score 0):

You just Replace border-style: hidden; to border:none;

In that column you not set border apply **style="border:none;"**